# sample from given distribution

Tags: r, text, random, distribution

I have a text file with a distribution of values, one on each row eg:

```
2313213.32
321233.23
97938.23
21323
211555
```

How do I randomly sample from this distribution 1000 times with replacement and get the mean from this random sampling? 
Preferably using R.

Thank you in advance,

Rubal

Comment: `help.search("sample")` and a little reading would have answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#test<-readLines('your.file')
#test<-as.numeric(test)

test<-c(2313213.32,321233.23,97938.23,21323,211555)

out<-sample(test,1000,replace=TRUE)

out.mean<-mean(out)
> out.mean
[1] 618679.5
```

Comment: +1 although I strongly advise you write `replace=TRUE` to prevent confusion when the object `T` has a value other than `TRUE`.

Comment: thanks, i actually have a lage file, around 800 lines, is it better to import the file and specify refer to that, than copy and paste in all the values?