# building an R loop for random sampling

Tags: r, loops, text, sample

I am sampling from a file containing a list of many values eg:

```
312313.34
243444
12334.92
321312
353532
```

and using R to randomly sample from this list:

```
list = read.table("data")
out <-sample(list,50,replace=TRUE)
out.mean<-mean(out)
out.mean
```

Could somebody please show me how to put this into a loop, so that I can perform this procedure 1000 times and take the mean of the 1000 means that this will generate?

Thank you very much in advance!

Rubal

Comment: possible duplicate of [sample from given distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128996/sample-from-given-distribution)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative solution could be (keep in mind what @Tyler Rinker just said about `replicate`)

```
Data <- read.table(text='
312313.34
243444
12334.92
321312
353532', header=FALSE)

Data <- as.numeric(as.matrix((Data))) 

set.seed(007)
Means <- replicate(1000, mean(sample(Data,50,replace=TRUE)))
```

Means consists of 1000 mean each one for every subsample of size 50. If you want the mean of the means do this:

```
mean(Means)
```

What you're trying to do sounds like a bootstrapping or something similar to resample techniques for bias reduction (I guess).

Answer (score 5):

I'd make a function out of the sampling and then repeat that over and over with `lapply` (though `replicate` would likely work too I've had experiences with this being much slower)

I'd recommend not write to an object named `list` as this is an important function.

So it would look something like this:

```
#make a data set that may look like yours
LIST <- rnorm(1000)

#take your code and make a function   
mean.find <- function(dat) {
    out <-sample(dat, 50,replace=TRUE)
    mean(out)
}

#a single use yo check it out 
mean.find(LIST)

#repeat it 1000 times with lapply
reps <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(1000), mean.find))

#take the mean of that
mean(reps)
```

Comment: +1 and Some nitpicking;). The function `mean.find` has an input argument which is not used: `dat`. Best would to either omit it, or use it i.e. `out<-sample(dat,50,replace=TRUE)`. This makes the function more general, you can get 50 samples for any dataset, and the code does not depend on scope finding a global variable calldd `LIST`.

Comment: @Paul good catch, that was my intention but I never followed through.  I made the edit as you suggested. `nitpicking = growth` :D

Comment: Using global objects from within functions makes me a bit uneasy, although I use it quite alot. In short scripts the risk probably small, but in larger projects it can lead to unpredictable behavior.